# Remap MapViewOfFile while keeping the same address

Tags: winapi, virtual-memory

The underlying problem I wish to solve is to have two regions of virtual memory that is backed by physical memory (ie, VirtualAlloc), and a third region of virtual memory that "points" to one of the other two regions of virtual memory.

While I believe you can map one of the two backed regions of memory with MapViewOfFileEx, I can't find any way of ensuring that the lpBaseAddress doesn't get stolen when changing the mapping from one region to another region.

My initial idea was to VirtualAlloc with MEM_RESERVE, but MapViewOfFileEx can't use reserved memory.

I believe I can accomplish the same thing on posix with shm_open and family, as mmap can override mapped regions.

Comment: i be say that your question unclear, *two regions of virtual memory* and *third region of virtual memory that "points" to one of the other two regions of virtual memory* - for what ?

Comment: As [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffileex) states it is suggested to use offset instead of address because there is no guarantee that the address will remain safe over time. Do you have any concern of using offset?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT It's an optimisation for emulation. There are two banks of emulated memory (the first two regions of virtual memory), and it would simplify the code if I could simply use the third region to point to the appropriate bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly override the address if it is in use.

To use the same address (`mappedAddress`) you need call `UnmapViewOfFile` before remap. Something like this:

```
HANDLE targetFile = CreateFile(L"target.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
HANDLE fileMap = CreateFileMapping(targetFile, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 10, L"myTestMap");
LPVOID mappedAddress = MapViewOfFileEx(fileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0, 0);
BOOL result = UnmapViewOfFile(mappedAddress); // Get the address.

HANDLE targetFile2 = CreateFile(L"target2.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
HANDLE fileMap2 = CreateFileMapping(targetFile2, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 10, L"myTestMap2");
LPVOID mappedAddress2 = MapViewOfFileEx(fileMap2, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0, mappedAddress); // Use the same address.
```

Comment: The only problem I can think of is a possible race condition between unmapping and remapping, where a VirtualAlloc steals the mappedAddress.

Comment: @Programmdude You can use [`VirtualLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtuallock) before `UnmapViewOfFile` to prevent from stealing.